# C#/SQL, I Would like to select all projects on a specific company

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, combobox

The problem is when i choose a company on my combobox1, 
all the projects on that company should be outputed on combobox2. 
but not when i choose a company on my comboBox1 it only output 1project on comboBox2. I want to output all the projects from that company.

Here's my code on selecting the `project_name` on a specific company

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    conn.Open();
    string query = "select project_name" +
                   "from JO.dbo.Proj left join JO.dbo.Comp" +
                   "on Proj.company_id = Comp.company_id" +
                   "where company_name = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "'";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            comboBox2.Text = reader["project_name"].ToString();
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    conn.Close();
    conn.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: `comboBox2.Text = reader["project_name"].ToString();` is this is the way to bind combo box?

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the comboBox2.Text property instead add the project name to the combobox2.Items.

```
       {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        conn.Open();
        string query = "select project_name from JO.dbo.Proj left join JO.dbo.Comp on Proj.company_id = Comp.company_id where company_name = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "'";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Clear();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Add(reader["project_name"].ToString());
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you convert you data into a list of Entity and bind that Entity to the combo box. What you are trying to do is not right way of binding data to a combo box

Basically ComboBox.Text Property:
Gets or sets the text associated with this control.

For more details please refer:

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is the obligatory "don't concatenate data into sql" warning; search for "bobby tables" to understand what you are doing **very very wrong** here; however, to be helpful - here's a suggestion on how you can reduce the code involved *and* get the right answer:

```
var projects = connection.Query<string>(
      @"select project_name
        from JO.dbo.Proj left join JO.dbo.Comp
          on Proj.company_id = Comp.company_id
        where company_name = @companyName",
      new { companyName = comboBox1.SelectedItem }).ToList();
```

After this line, `projects` is a `List<string>` of all the projects for that company; note how the `@companyName` is parameterized to prevent SQL injection. This uses the `Query<T>(this DBConnection, ...)` extension method that is provided by [dapper](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper) - which is freely available on NuGet.

Once you have the `List<string>` you can add those the the combo-box trivially.